# Invalid types int[int] for array subscript error

Tags: c++

I keep receiving the error listed above for my methods. Here is the relevant code:

```
BubbleSort<int> bs;
analysis << "Working with Bubble Sort with " << size << " random elements\n";
start = clock();
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
{
   bs.sort(array[size], 1+(rand() )); --> error
}
```

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef BUBBLESORT_H_
#define BUBBLESORT_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class BubbleSort
{
    private:

    public:
    int array[], size;
    Type sort(Type array[], Type size);
};

    template<class Type> 
    Type
    BubbleSort<Type>::sort(Type array[], Type size)
    {
        int i, j, flag = 1;
        int num_cmps = 0;
        int temp;
        for (i = 1; (i <= size) && flag; i++)
        {
        flag = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < (size - 1); j++)
            {
                if(array[j+1] < array[j])
                {
                temp = array[j];
                ++num_cmps;
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                ++num_cmps;
                array[j+1] = temp;
                ++num_cmps;
                flag = 1;
                ++num_cmps;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #endif
```

Previously I had asked the user for the number of elements and then `cin >> size;`. I thought this would make `size` constant, which is what my research has told me is the problem with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `int array[]` in your class definition is illegal; you must specify a size.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

In `BubbleSort`, instead of

```
Type sort(Type array[], Type size);
```

You need something like:

```
Type sort(Type array[], size_t size);
```

**Problem 2**

When you call the function,

`array[size]` evaluates to an `int`, not an array. Use:

```
bs.sort(array, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bs.sort(array[size], 1+(rand() ));
```

The function `sort` requires an array, but you are passing the item in `array` at index `size` (possibly out of bound)